# How do you create an Azure deployable WebRole that use LiveId and Access Control Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I need some help with creating a simple WebRole that uses federated authorzation/authentication with LiveId and the Access Control Service.  I'm able to get it working with a local test ASP.NET application, but can't seem to find any information on the steps necessary to do this with a Web Role that can be deployed to Azure.  The only information that I've found is to handle this scenario using a custom STS and the ACS or just LiveID, but nothing that demonstrates using both together.

Is there currently a limitation with Azure that prevents this?  I've read some articles that seem to indicate it isn't currently possible due to the Geneva Framework not being fully implemented on Azure - can anyone confirm?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You may find this resource useful - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wifwazpassive. It shows how to use ACS in an Azure Webrole. It does use a custom STS, not LiveID, but given that it's using Geneva framework components it should be possible to make it work with LiveID.